# Parse HTML from a nested JSON file with AngularJS

Tags: html, json, angularjs, nested

I am trying to parse nested JSON with AngularJS. There are items in it which will used throughout the page, however there are also nested news items in there. I'm not sure how to work this out.

test.json

```
{
  "CustomerName" : "TEST",
  "PaidCustomer" : true,
  "LaunchEndDate" : "24-07-2021",
  "LauncherTitle" : "Launcher Title",
  "LauncherSlogan" : "LauncherSlogan",
  "CommunityLogo" : "logo.jpg",
  "news" : [
    {
      "Title" : "News 1",
      "Description" : "Newsmessage 1",
      "FeaturesImage" : "",
      "Author" : "Hutserino",
      "Tags" : [ "#launcher", "#HellYeah" ],
    },
    {
      "Title" : "News 2",
      "Description" : "news 2",
      "FeaturesImage" : "",
      "Author" : "Hutserino",
      "Tags" : [ "#launcher", "#HellYeah" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've already tried this:

Angular code

```
<script>
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', []);

  function myController($scope, $http) {
    return $http.get('launcher.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });

    return {
      LauncherTitle: LauncherTitle,
      LauncherSlogan: LauncherSlogan
    }

    var data = response.data;

    data.forEach(data.news, function(clientdata.news, index) {
      angular.forEach(clientdata.news, function(newsitem, index){
        $scope.news.push(newsitem);
      });
    });

  }
})();

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
                  <h1 class="display-3">{{ GameLauncherTitle }}</h1>
                  <h3 class="display-5">{{ GameLauncherSlogan }}</h3>
    
    <div class="card-columns">
                  <div class="card" ng-repeat="newsitem in news">
                    <img src="{{ newsitem.FeaturesImage }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-dark">{{ newsitem.Title }}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text text-dark">{{ newsitem.Description }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

But this isn't returning any results.

Comment: What is this part: `return $http.get('launcher.json').then(function(response) {return response.data;});`
supposed to be?

Comment: I've readed multiple articles about this, and merged the codes together, though this was the correct way. Anyway return response.data has to return like LauncherSlogan and LauncherLogo etc.. All data which is not in the news part.

Comment: Yes, but arent you quitting of your `myController`? The function ends at a return statement, so the entire data section isnt run

Comment: Like I said im still learning :) can you give me any examples or an article where to do this like it shouldbe?

Comment: I have no idea what the returns are supposed to do, its a mess. You might want to take a look at JS before you learn angular. That said, I have a pretty good Idea what you were trying to do, so expect an answer in a few minutes

Comment: @downloadPizza I appreciate that, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218546/discussion-between-downloadpizza-and-dutchsociety).

Answer (score 0):

You are quitting out of your `myController` function with the two returns, I think you might have been trying

```js
(function() {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.news = []

    $http.get('launcher.json')
    .then(function(r) {return JSON.parse(r)})
    .then(function(response) {
      response.news.forEach(function(newsitem){
          $scope.news.push(newsitem);
        });
      });
    });
})();
```

Can you try this instead of your Angular Code?

Cleaned version:

```js
(() => {
  const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('myController', ($scope, $http) => {
    $scope.news = []
    $http.get('launcher.json')
      .then(r => JSON.parse(r))
      .then(response => {
        response.news.forEach(function (newsitem) {
          $scope.news.push(newsitem);
        })
      })
  })
})();
```

Comment: Im sorry but this isnt the solution for me, it is not parsing anything.